# JS Google Maps breaks fixed element

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I have a site with a fixed navigation bar that should scroll with the page. When I add a JS Google Map, the nav bar no longer moves:

http://amosjackson.com/map/index.html

Also, the problem only occurs when the map is absolutely positioned.

Comment: This is both a browser related issue (it works well with Chrome but not on FF), and also has something to do with the z-index.

Giving a negative z-index less than "-1" as you did to the map should fix the issue.

Comment: @DanieleB it works when I give the map a positive z-index but now I can't get the text to go on top.

Comment: adding an z-index to the text element greater than the one of the map could work...

Answer (score 11):

Add translateZ to the fixed element

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

I found out while analysing the whole google map canvas. The API adds also a
`-webkit-transform: translateZ(0)` to the map. this breaks many browsers in painting the fixed elements correctly.

In addition the fixed element could also need other related visibility properties like `z-index` and opacity.

A working solution: (I always put my map canvas into a container)

```
.my-fixed-elem {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  z-index: 500 // adapt for your project
  opacity: 1 // some times you can remove this
}

.map-canvas-container {
    width: 100%; // somewidth
    height: 750px; // someheight
    position: relative;
    z-index: 18;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#map-canvas-contact {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Best regards

Comment: This seems to resolve the rendering problems, but disrupts keyframe animations (at least in Chrome: 35.0.1916.114).  Any thoughts on how to resolve this without disrupting animations or resorting to ugly hacks?

Comment: adding the transform props to teh fixed element helped resolve this issue. Interestingly, this only happens in Chrome - FF and IE both rendered this without issue.

Answer (score 0):

remove the z-index from the google maps div and also give it an opacity value such that the text becomes visible.. play around with them..

hope that helps..

Answer (score 0):

It is some sort of webkit bug related to the "transform" css setting that is added to the outer maps element.  The transform:translateZ(0px) is added in a style attribute, but does not need to be in there, removing it has no effect.

So the answer is to add a css line to the page and use the !important flag so it will override the style attribute's setting.

```
<style>
#map-canvas[style] { -webkit-transform:none !important; }
</style>
```

Note, the [style] part makes it only take effect if google adds the style attribute, and the #map-canvas may need to be changed to match the element you sent to google.maps.Map()