# Lost Hover Styling in Chrome for Mac

Tags: html, macos, css, google-chrome

Can be replicated by scrolling past the header, then trying to hover over a menu item.

Here's a link to the website: http://fire.wakeyyc.com

And since I can't post pictures, here is a link to a picture to outline the problem:

http://fire.wakeyyc.com/images/glitch.png

Thanks for your help everyone! :)

Comment: which browser you are trying??? it is working in chrome.

Comment: Nope, it's broken in Chrome. I'm assuming you didn't try clicking 'Speakers', 'Featuring', 'Location', 'Contact Us', or scrolling part way down the page and then trying to hover over the menu items.

Comment: are you saying broken in chrome means?? is it not scrolling to particular section???

Comment: No, the scrolling is working. The problem is that the hover styling isn't showing up in Chrome. It's supposed to show border bottom and turn the text color teal on hover.

Comment: yes sir! it is working absolutely fine in all the browsers.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Chrome for Mac if that helps. I tried it on two different computers and still had the same problem.

Comment: please check the attached image below, i dont know what is the reason ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've found the solution myself. It turns out that there is a glitch in Chrome that when you add a JS Google Map while having a fixed item on your page, you'll run into z-indexing problems.

The problem is caused by a style of `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` applied by google to their JS Maps.

The source for my answer is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365604/js-google-maps-breaks-fixed-element) although my answer is slightly modified.

Add a `transform: translateZ(0);` along with all the different vendor extensions to the ul element and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

**it is working in chrome.**

below is the attached screenshot.

[image]

my suggestion clear the catche or update the chrome version and TRY.

Comment: Hey,thanks for trying. :) I did what you suggested and it's still not working. From the looks of your picture, it's showing an a:active or a:visited type styling but if you were to hover over 'Speakers' with your mouse at this point, the styling wont show. I'm talking about an a:hover here. I tried attatching a picture but I'm too new to stackoverflow and it won't let me.

Comment: friend I'm also talking about an a:hover,it is working . some times we will experience weird errors. may be check it in other people's computer or it is not showing because mine is windows yours in Mac

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot for your help. I guess it's just a sneaky glitch that doesn't want to be found. :P It doesn't affect usability so I guess it's not a big deal. Thanks again.